# Prevent the query from generating multiple unnecessary columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this so far when trying to find the total time traveled based on the "generation" column:

```
SELECT
    generation,
    SUM(CASE WHEN generation = 'Millennials' THEN Rental_Duration_seconds END) AS MillennialTT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN generation = 'Generation Z' THEN Rental_Duration_seconds END) AS GenZTT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN generation = 'Generation X' THEN Rental_Duration_seconds END) AS GenXTT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN generation = 'Baby Boomers' THEN Rental_Duration_seconds END) AS BBYBoomerTT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN generation = 'Silent Generation' THEN Rental_Duration_seconds END) AS SilentGenTT
FROM
    dbo.2019_Q2_Trips
GROUP BY
    generation;
```

This query would then generate a table with multiple columns with NULL values that are unnecessary. I could make the NULL values 0 with the ELSE statement, but it doesn't make the columns go away.

Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't generate multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
SELECT generation, SUM(Rental_Duration_Seconds) 
FROM 2019_Q2_Trips 
GROUP BY generation;
```